# Отображение каждого 5 элемента в цикле

Tags: objective-c, xcode, циклы

У меня есть цикл:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    

for (int min = 0; min < 6; min++)
    for (int sec = 0; sec < 60; sec++)
    {

        [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d",min, sec]];
    }
self.time = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
```

и идет отображение каждого элемента. Как сделать, чтобы отображался каждый пятый? Например, **0:0, 0:5, 0:10**, и так далее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю, что у Вас и как, но может быть так:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    

for (int min = 0; min < 6; min++) {
    for (int sec = 0; sec < 60; sec+=5) {
        [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d", min, sec]];
    }
    self.time = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
}
```

Comment: да, точно, спасибо!)

Comment: @DavidKakaladze бывает)

Comment: кстати, а почему у Вас вложенный for не в {}?

Comment: ну он и так работает

Comment: а строчка self.time = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray]; у вас относится к for или она вне цикла?

Comment: относится к for

Comment: @DavidKakaladze тогда все-таки это должно быть внутри {}, а так в первом for у тебя только второй for находится, а та строка вне

Comment: добавил {} все также работает и отображается, а в чем смысл?

Comment: @DavidKakaladze сперва скажи, правильно отображается?

Comment: да, в обоих вариантах

Comment: @DavidKakaladze просто бывает однострочный for, в котором допускается не использовать фигурные скобки, лишь из-за того, что в таком форе обычно заключен только один оператор, а если тебе нужно, чтобы фор выполнил несколько действий(операторов), то нужно заключать в фигурные скобки, если же ты забудешь заключить все эти действия(операторы) в скобки, то он просто будет выполнять первый оператор, а остальные будет считать как вне цикла

Comment: ясно, спасибо за разъяснения! поправлю в коде.